# How to get Url data need to extract as array format

Tags: php, arrays, url

How to get from url inside data as array format in php.

http://ekkanoo.com/api/NewsFeeds/json/toyota-news/0/15?callback=

i have try various code but i not able to get as array format.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @stefan how to retrive data as array using php.

Comment: Post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you want your your url as `array` then probably you are looking for `explode`

> ref - **[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**

Suppose your file has the following code

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test jQuery</title>
    <script src="../jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="new_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Get content of url file

```
<?php 
  $fileString = file_get_contents("index.php");
  $fileArr = explode("\n",$string);
  print_r($fileArr);
  ?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => <!DOCTYPE html>
    [1] => <html lang="en">
    [2] => <head>
    [3] =>  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    [4] =>  <title>Test jquery</title>
    [5] =>  <script src="../jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>   
    [6] => </head>
    [7] => 
    [8] => <body>
    [9] =>  <div id="new_div"></div>
    [10] => </body>
    [11] => </html>
)
```

Comment: i need the data inside the url as array

Comment: See the answer now @Ayyan

Comment: your ourput is right but i need that output for the url inside data.

Comment: Are you able to get output for http://ekkanoo.com/api/NewsFeeds/json/toyota-news/0/15?callback=      For this url as array @meenesh Jain

Comment: yes i am but now the url has a json within brackets. remove the brackets and change your json to array

Comment: That is the feed we not able to change.

Answer (score -1):

as I understood, you need this http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

From the documentation:

> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.
>   This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly